# is there a way to update multiple colomn with spesific part?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and inside there's a birth date, one of the worker serial number is almost the same as the birth date and since some of the serial number data is not the same as their birth date I wanted to update those date as the same as their serial number.

I use this kind of code

```
UPDATE worker 
SET birthdate = MID(NIP,1,8) 
where (MID(NIP,1,8)
<>concat(MID(TGLLHR,1,4),MID(TGLLHR,6,2),MID(TGLLHR,9,2)));
```

- the 3rd line is for searching birthdate that not the same as serial number
- the 2nd line is the one I wanted to change instead of getting output like 1996-08-01 the one that I got just like 19960801... I wanted to change it like date format 
  For example if one of them have serial number `19961101013` and their birth date is `1995-11-03` I wanted to change their birth date as same as the serial number like `1996-11-01`

Comment: You can't change someone's birth date ;)

Comment: hahaha most of their birthdate is false and the right combination of their birthdate is in the serial number that's why i wanted to change those birthdate

Comment: your question is not clear try add  a proper data sample, your actual result  and the expected  result as  tabular data  ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use couple or REPLACE/CONVERT method to check data matching between birthdate and NIP and then UPDATE data accordingly. The following script will help you to update your data accordingly.

> Note: UPDATE is a risky command. Please try with your test data first.

```
UPDATE worker 
SET birthdate = CONVERT(LEFT(CONVERT(NIP,CHAR),8) , DATE)
WHERE REPLACE(CONVERT(birthdate, CHAR),'-','') <> LEFT(CONVERT(NIP,CHAR),8)
```

The above script will only UPDATE records that has mismatch between birthdate and NIP value as you explained.